# Allowing users to 'toggle' up_vote and down_vote using thumbs_up gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the [thumbs_up gem](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up) to allow 'likes' in my app.

The gem includes this code to make sure that one user cannot vote twice -

```
Code '1'
# Comment out the line below to allow multiple votes per user.
validates_uniqueness_of :voteable_id, :scope => [:voteable_type, :voter_type, :voter_id]
```

But I want my users to be able to 'up_vote' once, then 'down_vote' if they happen to like by mistake (for user experience's sake). I tried to change the scope to:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :voteable_id, :scope => [:voteable_type]
```

But that would allow users to 'up_vote' twice in a row. Users, instead, should only be able to 'down_vote' if the voteable object is already 'up_vote'd, and vice versa.

I can think of doing this by using a conditional in my view, as such:

```
<% if !current_user.voted_for?(voteable_name) %>
     <%= link_to('Like', vote_up_question_answer_path(voteable_name), :method => :post) %>
<% else %>
     <br>
     <%= link_to('Unlike', vote_down_question_answer_path(voteable_name), :method => :post) %>
<% end %>
```

And commenting out Code '1', but is there a better way to make users permitted to only 'toggle'-ing between the votes through the controller?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you check out the gem acts_as_votable it has that functionality built in, it also has support for weighted votes.

Comment: @CoreyGibson Thanks, I've browsed that gem too and I think I'll switch after reading up on it (the merit gem has been having another error recently). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should probably implement the flipping in application code instead of changing the existing behavior of the library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In that case, would I need to allow voters to vote multiple times and then implement a conditional in the app?

Comment: What you want to do @sofarsophie on the second request you want to edit the existing vote rather than creating a new one. But yeah, there's better gems for this problem.

Comment: @ThomasR.Koll Right, okay I think I can try that. Do you have any recommendations for alternative gems I can use (are you referring to acts_as_votable too?)? When I restarted my server, this merit gem had a no method issue that is apparently still being fixed... I think I will switch to a new one.

Comment: acts_as_votable as @Corey Gibson recommended.

Comment: Thanks, will check out. :)